# Клиент-серверное приложение на Java (мессенджер)

Tags: java, sql, apache

Здравствуйте. В качестве проектной работы решил написать мессенджер, но я почти что не представляю, как они вообще работают и пишутся. 
Как я понимаю, для каждого зарегистрированного пользователя создается таблица в БД (SQL, например), запускается сервер, который связан с этой БД, а при работе мессенджера каждый зарегистрированный пользователь обращается к этой БД. Так вот 
как происходит взаимодействие двух пользователей? Как применяется Apache? Пожалуйста, киньте хотя бы ссылки на нужную литературу или статьи. 
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В основе мессенджера лежит протокол взаимодействия, который описывает процедуры регистрации пользователей, подписку на услуги, формат сообщений и многое прочее. Вы сразу пытаетесь копать реализацию, перепрыгнув логику взаимодействия. Можете взять [один из открытых стандартов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_instant_messaging_protocols). Например, XMPP или SIP. Когда разберетесь с архитектурой и обогатитесь терминологией можно будет продумывать детали реализации.

Answer (score 3):

Смотря что за прожект.
Просто показать, что работает, с минимальными усилиями? Можно посмотреть в сторону JMS.

Для каждого пользователя заводится очередь. Вся деятельность сводится к чтению, записи мессаг из/в очередь.

С базой данных пересечения самые минимальные. Только список пользователей с их логинами.
JMS имеет свою базу сообщений, с которой управляется сам без посторонних вмешательств. Сообщения там если и хранятся, то только временно до успешной доставки адресату.

JMS поставляется в составе серверов JavaEE Full Profile. Бесплатные Wildfly, Glassfish, Payara.

Есть и другие решения для messaging.
Очень популярен RabbitMQ.
В Windows-е можно сразу же установить службу очереди сообщений. Но не знаю есть ли для неё клиент на java.

Вообще это всё имеет название `message queuing`. Можно легко нагуглить руководства в картинках.

Правда велика вероятность нажить геморрой, внедряя jms в программу. Всего-то пара-тройка строчек/параметров, но должны быть правильными. А информация в гугле очень неточная.

А Apache нам не нужен.